# D8 multisite won't use correct subfolder for database credentials - only default

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a site fully functional.
Sitename: something.com, something.com/da, something.com/ru.

I´ve now got a full copy and I wan´t to create:
something.dev, something.dev/da, something.dev/ru.

Ever regular code setup matches. DB, sites.php and runs!

```
sites/da
sites/ru

core
da -> ./
ru -> ./
sites
themes

da/
 files
 services.yml
 settings.php
default/
 files
 default.services.yml
 default.settings.php
 services.yml
 settings.php
 settings.local.php
```

sites.php:

```
<?php

    $sites=array(
        'something.dev.da' => 'da',
        'something.dev.ru' => 'ru'
    );

?>
```

If I remove symlinks something.dev/da doesn't work.

1. I remove symlinks
2. Russian: I attach full path to synlinks. ln -s pwd ru
3. I go to something.dev/ru

AND IT USES THE DEFAULT DIRECTORY (sites/settings.php) :-(
.... not sites/ru/settings.php

If I create a new fresh install of D8 and do the same process, everything works. But I need the site working with all modules, DB and stuff. Too much work trying to setup like this.

I tried to clean the database for past URL´s, still nothing.

Any help appreciated <3! Thanks!

Image of my directory - https: 
cl.ly/2y0t0u3k161J

:::: IF I rename folder "default" to "_default" new core install shows up.

DA/RU seems to use the default no matter what I do,

Comment: Did you add the redirects in your sites.php file in the sites folder?

Comment: I'm using one codebase and subfolders for new languages.
Main language is root and da/ru uses other database settings

Comment: I've added a image of my directory. I couldn't upload image here... But : cl.ly/2y0t0u3k161J with https

Comment: @PascalClaes Will you check? :-)

Comment: You haven't answered my question?

Comment: @PascalClaes I've shown my sites.php above in my description.     $sites=array( 'something.dev.da' => 'da','something.dev.ru' => 'ru');.... And I only use one codebase except sites/subfolders. Only thing that changes is settings.php more or less.

Comment: Looks fine, you might have to remove the default option

Comment: @PascalClaes Indeed, that´s the problem :-/ ..... I've just tried removing default setting as well and symlinked again. Still - I can't make "/da" "/ru" use correct settings.php even though it´s setup..... No idea how I can fix this? :-I